# Magnitude of the time derivative of angular momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rigid-body-dynamics, angular-velocity

This is a problem involving a stick of mass m and length l which spins with frequency ω around an axis, as shown in the figure below. The stick makes an angle θ with the axis

The goal was to find the angular momentum and the magntude of the time derivative of the angular momentum.
I completely understand how to calculate the angular momentum but i am confused with the magntiude of the derivative.

I do understand that only the horizontal component of the angular momentum vector changes over time in a circular motion and the vertical component stays fixed. I do understand that the horizontal component of $L$ is $Lcos(\theta)$. I do not understand why $|dL/dt|$ is equal to $w * Lcos(\theta)$.

EDIT : Why do we multiply $w$ to the horizontal component of L to get the |dL/dt|? $w$ is the angular velocity of the horizontal component of L around that axis and $Lcos(θ)$ is the magnitude of that horizontal component, or the length of that horizontal vector. Why do wet get the magnitude $dL/dt$ if we multiply those two?

[image: "From the book Classical Mechanics by David Morin"]

Figure from the book "Classical Mechanics" by David Morin

Comment: What do you think the result should be?

Comment: I dont know to be honest, could you give me a tip?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What causes trouble for you? Is it $\omega$? Is it $\cos(\theta)$? Is it the projection? Is it the fact that you're taking the derivative of a moving vector? If you don't give more details about the exact point of the computation that leaves you stuck, it's difficult to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: its why we mulitply $w$ to the horizontal component of $L$ to get the $|dL/dt|$? 
$w$ is the angular velocity of the horizontal component of $L$ around that axis and $Lcos(\theta)$ is the magnitude of that horizontal component, or the length of that horizontal vector.  Why do wet get the magnitude $dL/dt$ if we multiply those two?

Comment: You should add this to your question (by editing). Comments can be deleted, so important details mustn't be there.

Comment: oke, ive done so, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moment of inertia of the rod for this rotation axis is:
$$J=\frac{1}{12}\,ml^2\sin(\theta)$$
so its angular momentum is:
$$\vec{L}=J\omega\,\vec{u}$$
with $\vec{u}$ the unit vector carrying $\vec{L}$ according to your figure.

The general formula for the derivative of a vector gives (for a vector in pure rotation):
$$\frac{d\vec{L}}{dt}
=\vec{\omega}\times\vec{L}
=\omega L\,\vec{u}_z\times\vec{u}$$
with $\vec{\omega}=\omega\,\vec{u}_z$ the rotation vector (alongside the rotation axis). Taking the norm on both sides:
$$\left\lVert\frac{d\vec{L}}{dt}\right\rVert
=\omega L\left\lvert\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)\right\rvert
=\omega L\lvert\cos(\theta)\rvert$$
and since $\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$, the absolute value isn't necessary, hence the result.

Comment: Thank you, that general formula was very helpful, i have tried it again my way and the result was exaclty the same. Thank you very much! Im sorry that i dont have enough reputation to upvote your post but ill accept this answer.

Comment: Keep in mind that the vector derivative formula has an extra term in the most general case. See [this page](https://orbital-mechanics.space/review/time-derivatives-of-moving-vectors.html).

Comment: ahh yes, ill check that page, thank you again!